# What does '->' indicate in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

In the pseudo code below for reversing a linked list.  How to read the first line in the while block?  From what I've read about pseudo code, the arrow would be interpreted as saying 'next becomes equal to current'.  If that is the case then why not just 'next = current'?  Is there more information the arrow is providing that I'm missing?

```
while (current != None)
{
  next = current -> next;
  current -> next = prev;
  prev = current;
  current = next;
}
*head_ref = prev
```

Comment: There is no standard for pseudocode. It means whatever the author wants it to mean. In this case, it's the C `->` operator.

Comment: In C and C++, the expression `current->next` is equivalent to `(*current).next`. `*` is the pointer dereference operator and `.` is the `struct` member access operator.